# DataTables mRender function with view model

Tags: javascript, data-binding, knockout.js, datatables

I'm implement table as http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/form.html, but in javascript I can't data-bind values from my viewmodel("vm") in "mRender". With test render function work correctly. How implement binding with viewmodel in javascript code?

```
 function CreateNewDllTable(url, vm) {
    var oTable = $('#test-table').dataTable({
            "bProcessing": true,
            "bServerSide": true,
            "bPaginate": false,
            "scrollY": "250px",
            "bSort": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bInfo": false,
            "sAjaxDataProp": "dataValues",
            "sAjaxSource": url
            },
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "name" },
            {                        
                 type: 'text',
                "mData": "description",
                "mRender": function (data) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        return '<input type="text"/>';
                    } else {
                        return '<input type="text"/>';
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "mRender": function (data) {
                    return "<select class='multiselect'>"
                                + "<option>Value1</option>"
                                + "<option>Value2</option>"
                                + "<option>Value3</option>"
                                + "<option>Value4</option>"
                                + "<option>Value5</option>"
                            + "</select>";
                }
            }
            ],
             "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                $("select.multiselect").multiselect();           
            }, 
    }
```

For example binding in html:

```
  <select class="multiselect" data-bind="
        options: vm.types,
        value: vm.selectedTypeId,
        optionsText:'type',
        optionsValue: 'typeId'">
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        For example you can used this code:

       "mRender": function () {
var returnValue = "<select class='multiselect'>";
var types = vm.types;
var listItems = "";
for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {                                           
       listItems += "<option value='" + types[i].typeId + "'" + " selected='selected'" + ">" + types[i].type + "</option>";                                           
}
return returnValue.concat(listItems, "</select>");       
}
```